# Converting docx files to WPF Flow Documents

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, docx

I'm trying to convert a bunch of **Microsoft Word** documents, containing a few pictures and many lines of text and headings to **Flow Documents**.

I found [this](http://khason.net/blog/wordml-to-flowdocument-%e2%80%93-how-to-convert-docx-files-to-wpf-flowdocument/) article useful, but I couldn't add images form **docx** files to **Flow Documents** properly.

A sample code or some guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the more popular converters: [Word to XAML Converter](http://wordtoxaml.codeplex.com/). It ain't perfect, but it's a great start. There's also a good article on this subject at [OpenXML + FlowDocument = OpenFlowDocument?](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/OpenFlowDoc.aspx) which is for WPF. Finally, you can check out [TextGlow](http://textglow.codeplex.com) - although it's for Silverlight and not using FlowDocument, it's good to see how he does some of the conversions with Linq.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can check out this article: [Show Word file in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649064/Show-Word-file-in-WPF)

This is also not a complete solution, but I believe it can be easily enhanced, the article has a really nice explanation of DOCX file elements and their corresponding FlowDocument elements.